# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown [selected] attribute not working with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular5

Link to demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq35ac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedColumnModel"
  (change)="onColumnSelect(selectedColumnModel)" 
  style="height: 150px; width: 200px"
  multiple
>
  <option 
    *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index;" 

    [ngValue]="column"
    [selected]="selectedColumns[i]?.title == column.title"
  >
    {{ column.title }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I have a multi-select drop-down, on page load I want some values to be preselected.

If I delete [(ngModel)] it is working perfectly, how can I make it work with [(ngModel)]

Some people suggested using [compareWith]. 
Here is the link: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

But I'm not sure how to use that here. Please Help.

Comment: Try ngx-bootstrap for this sort of functionality. These bootstrap behaviours generally don't play well with angular out of the box. That's why libraries like ngx-bootstrap exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign the preselected values to `selectedColumnModel`

```
selectedColumnModel = ['UID','NAME','BRANCH' ];
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ar6m7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)